# How to change the width of a layout object in an appwidget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appwidget

I want to use the same layout in several formats. Therefore, I have to change the size.

How can I change the width of the RelativeLayout with the id picframe programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/picframe"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overlay"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
...
```

I've tried

```
remoteView.setString(R.id.picframe, "setWidth", "50dp");
```

and

```
remoteView.setString(R.id.picframe, "setLayoutWidth", "50dp");
```

without success.

Comment: Did you got a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try.  I'd make the top level view a `<merge>` instead of a relative layout, and merge it into a relative layout with the width you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the 'merge' Tag, but in this case it is need, because the layout is more complex than you can see in this sniplet.